# Is d3 edge labeling possible?

Tags: html, svg, d3.js

Is it possible to have edge labels in a graph using [d3](http://d3js.org/)? I've looked over the examples and some of the documentation, and I can see where node labeling is possible, but edge labeling is not explicitly mentioned anywhere (that I can find).

Comment: I assume you mean labeling such that the text follows the path of the graph. If so, SVG seems to have a [text on a path](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/text.html#TextOnAPath) feature in the spec, but I've never tried it, so not sure how easy it is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Following other peoples examples I

- add a `path` alongside every edge,
- add `text` to the edges
- bind that text to a `textpath` which is referencing the path along the edge

This example is using the above ideas: http://bl.ocks.org/jhb/5955887

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is "yes", but there's no explicit support for it. You'll have to determine the position of the label yourself. One way of doing this would be to attach the label to the start node and translate it by half the distance to the target node, plus some offset to prevent it overlapping the line. For more elaborate edges (e.g. curves) it would be more difficult.

Comment: http://bl.ocks.org/2926502 is an example of this approach, with a label near each end of each link. The label positions are recalculated on each tick.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the text on a path option, but it is quite involved and didn't result in the appearance I wanted. Unfortunately, I didn't check it into the local git repository. This comes from my Eclipse history (thanks Eclipse developers). You'll have to change this code snippet to your own data structure, but I'll hope it is of some help. In particular, notice the adding of the `id` value to the `lines` selection and then reusing it in the percentages selection by using the `xlink:href` attribute. Also, I appended a `tspan` in the `textpath` to move the text down by a couple of pixels so it appears over the path instead of on it.

```
        function drawLines(links) {
        var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal();
        var format = d3.format(".1%");
        var linkKey = function(l) {return l.target.key; };
        var lines = linesGroup.selectAll("path").data(links, linkKey);
        lines.enter()
            .append("path")
            .on("mouseover", select)
            .on("mouseout", unselect)
            .attr("d", diagonal)
            .attr("id", function (l) { return "interaction-path-target-" + l.target.key; })
            .style("stroke-width", 0.000001);
        lines.exit()
            .transition().duration(500)
            .style("stroke-width", 0.000001)
            .remove();

        lines.transition()
            .delay( function(d, i) { return i * 100; })
            .duration(500)
            .style("stroke-width", function(d) { return d.weight == 0 ? 0.000001 : d.weight / 1000; })
            .attr("d", diagonal);

        var percentages = linesGroup.selectAll("text").data(links, linkKey);
        percentages.enter()
            .append("text")
            .attr("opacity", 1)
            .append("svg:textPath")
            .attr("startOffset", "70%")
            .attr("xlink:href", 
                    function(l) { 
                        return "#interaction-path-target-" + l.target.key; 
                    })
            .append("svg:tspan")
            .attr("dy", 3)
            .attr("class", "percentageText")
        percentages.exit()
            .transition().duration(500)
            .attr("opacity", 0)
            .remove();
        percentages
            .transition()
            .delay( function(d, i) { return i * 100; })
            .duration(500)
            .attr("opacity", 1);

        percentages.select(".percentageText").text(function(d) {
                var newvalue = d.weight ?
                    d.incomming ? percentageIn(d.weight) : percentageOut(d.weight) : 0;
                return format(newvalue);
            });
    }
```