# How to add texts on both end of a link between nodes in d3

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

Expectation

[image: 1]

Can anyone give me some suggestion on how to add text on both end of a link between nodes in d3 svg?
I have no issue adding a text to a line in left, right or middle position. But what I really want to do is that I need text or label on both end of a link like as shown.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is d3 edge labeling possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984704/is-d3-edge-labeling-possible)

Comment: Not quit. it only adds one text on the path.